# How to classify rows having one or more related records

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, clickhouse

I need to add the additional column called rank_2 which will show whether the source has more than 1 source_ids.

So, I need to get this result:

[image]

I don't know how to write a query to get rank_2, which will contain 1 when the source has the only source_id (like the source "b") and contain 2 when the source has 2 or more source_ids (like the source "a").

Comment: Please post data as text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming window functions are available you can use a query like so:

```
select *
     , case when count(*) over (partition by date, source_name) = 1 then 1 else 2 end as rank_2
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

With the count function you will be able to resolve this problem:

, count(source_id) as rank_2

Don't forget to group by date, source_name, source_id.

I only don't understand why source_id 11 needs to get value 1 as it is also shown two times in the table.

Comment: It refers to different dates. So, the source "b" has the only source_id which is 11.